# Rails collection_select tag displays incorrectly when viewed using windows, but fine from OSX

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I use a collection_select tag that looks fine when viewed from a Mac, but when viewed from a pc running Windows, it appears like this:

[image: CollectionSelectFormatProblem]

I am using Chrome on both computers, so I was surprised to see that they appear differently.

The tag looks like this:

```
<%= collection_select :matchup, :player_2, Player.order('full_name ASC'), :id, :full_name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "matchupSearchField", id: "player_2_search_field" } %>
```

I am using bootstrap, and the css applicable to this tag is:

```
.matchupSearchField {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any thoughts as to why this would be happening?

If you would like to see it live, you can see the collection_select(s) in question near the bottom of this page: https://guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've bumped into one of the problem with padding calculation made by Chrome for dynamically sized elements on different platforms. Checkout this [post](https://coderwall.com/p/8qidzw).

**Hey, man, how did you find this error?**

Right click in Chrome on selector > Inspect element > Computed-tab on the right - compare results between OSX and Windows. On OSX you have 0px padding calculated (which is wrong according to CSS), while Windows does it correctly, setting to 10px.

The way to fix is to set padding for your selector explicitly to 0px in CSS